# How do you calculate modulo operation with real numbers in system verilog?

Tags: operators, system-verilog, modulo, test-bench

For example:

```
real a = 10.2917541278;
real modout;
assign modout = (a % 3.142);
```

Currently, this is not supported, I get an error saying numbers need to be integers.

I don't want this code to be synthesized. This is only in the testbench.

Comment: Maybe you can use division followed by subtraction. Something like this: `temp = int'(a / 3.142);` and `modout = a - (temp*3.142);`. Temp will store the integer quotient and modout will store the remainder/modulo.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of a modulus in real number math is a bit weird since the result of the division of two real numbers should be a real number (ignoring zero). If however, you want something like `fmod` in C/C++, you can implement it like so:

```
real x, d, r;
assign r = x - d * $floor(x / d); // Implements fmod(x, d) or "x % d" for real x, d
```